# Python pop. Trying to list pop (remove list ) into new variable (language)

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing, append

I'm currently learning a python language. I face the problem on this question.

[ ] pop the last language from your list and store it in a variable called language.

Those empty box I need to tick to chech the answer.

[image: This is the screenshot of my question]

After I tick, I will get prompted with "**language** should contain the string **'JavaScript'**"

Below is my code snippet.

```
courses = []
courses.append('Python')
courses.append('JavaScript')
print(courses)
removed_course = courses.pop()
print('Removed course:' + removed_course)

language = [removed_course]
language.append(removed_course)
print(language)
```

Comment: You're creating a new list with 2 elements in it but they just want a plain string, apparently. Try `language = removed_course` instead of the `append` and `[]` lines.

Comment: I've tried it before but it still prompted the same thing.

Comment: Please show that code you tried.

Comment: language = removed_course

Comment: That looks fine to me. Not sure what the problem is. If the test is public can you post a link? I'll try it out.

Comment: I don't whether you can access it or not because it is for Malaysian only but here is the [link] (https://www.elatih.com/p/#/app/course-view/23034669/overview?instance=23484658&logicSearchId=28131b0e-c266-4d2f-a9c4-68640e6fa8e2&selectedIndex=8)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230104/discussion-between-syirul-jo-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
languages = []
languages.append('Python')
languages.append('JavaScript')
print(languages)
language = languages.pop()
print('Removed course: ' + language)
print(languages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task says: '... store it in a variable called `language`'.

So, just use the first part of your code, with `language` instead of `removed_course`.

```
courses = []
courses.append('Python')
courses.append('JavaScript')
print(courses)
language = courses.pop()
print('Removed course: ' + language)
print(courses)
```

Output:

```
['Python', 'JavaScript']
Removed course: JavaScript
['Python']
```